# jQuery prototype inheritance

Tags: jquery, prototype

I wrote a little code for understanding the jQuery Prototype object `jQuery.fn` better, but I can't figure out why it is not working:

```
jQuery.fn.appender = function(text) {  
    // i want every jQuery-Element to inherit a method called appender (I know that there is already "append" - this is just for learning).
    this.each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).append(text);
    })
};

$("diveins").appender(); // nothing is happening
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue nothing to do with inheritance. It is because you're not providing a `text` parameter to your function. `diveins` is also not a valid selector. Presumably that should be `.diveins`. Finally note that your `each()` loop is redundant as jQuery will apply the `append()` method on each element in the set by default. Try this:

```js
$.fn.appender = function(text) {
  $(this).append(text);
};

$(".diveins").appender('foo'); // note the addition of the parameter here
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="diveins"></div>
<div class="diveins"></div>
<div class="diveins"></div>
```

When reduced to this level your function becomes simply a wrapper for `append()` which is a little redundant, but I assume you are going to add further logic to it.